# How to use local labels in procedures in TASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I wrote simple

```
.MODEL  small

.STACK 100h
.DATA 
    liczba dw 0h
    licznik dw 0
    potega dw 1
    liczbaString dw ?

    buff db 26
.CODE
  Program:
    mov ax, @DATA
    mov ds, ax

    call PobierzString
    call PetlaIteracjiZnaku

    ;zwraca do ax pobraną liczbę
    PetlaIteracjiZnaku PROC
        mov si, liczbaString
        call ZnajdzDlugoscString
        mov si, liczbaString
        add si, 2
        mov bl, 1
        petla:
            xor ax, ax
            mov al, [si]
            cmp al, 24h; sprawdza czy nie jest koniec wprowadzanej liczby '$'
            je return
            sub al, 30h ; odejmuję 30 żeby zamienić znak na liczbę
            mul bx
            add [liczba], ax
            mov ax, bx
            mov bx, 0Ah
            mul bx
            mov bx, ax
            inc si
        jmp petla
        return:
            ret
    PetlaIteracjiZnaku ENDP

    ; ! si - caly string 
    ; - ax - dlugosc stringu
    ZnajdzDlugoscString PROC
        mov al, 0h
        petla:
            mov dl, [si]
            cmp dl, 24h
            je return
            inc al
        jmp petla
        return: 
            ret
    ZnajdzDlugoscString ENDP

    PobierzString PROC
        xor ax,ax
        mov ah, 0Ah 
        mov dx, offset buff
        int 21h     
        mov liczbaString, dx
        ret
    PobierzString ENDP
    Koniec:
    mov     ah, 4ch
    int     21h

    end Program
```

But I can't compile it with tasm because I get error:

> Symbol already defined elswere: PETLA
>      Symbol already defined elswere: RETURN

How to use local labels for procedures? I tried to add `.PETLA` and `%%PETLA` as in [Use procedure scope to avoid local labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33657397/use-procedure-scope-to-avoid-local-labels) but it still doesn't work.
I have no idea how to achive this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use local labels in procedures with TASM you need to:

- Use the `@@` prefix for your label name; and
- Place `LOCALS @@` in the beginning of your file.

You can use a diferent prefix instead of `@@`, but `@@` is the common one.

See page 130 of the [TASM User's Guide](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf).