# What does character "@" mean in this i8086 Assembly code?

Tags: assembly

I'm struggling to understand the following code, specifically the second line. May someone please explain it to me.

I do understand basic commands but I cannot figure out the whole point here.

```
MOV BL, 2
@@1:
SUB BL, 1
JNS @@1 ;
```

Comment: Depending on the specific assembler used it may mean nothing at all (i.e. `@@1` may be just another label name), or it might signify a local label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the whole code is just like a loop in the high-level languages. the below code may help you to understand how it works.

```
int BL = 2;
lbl_@@1:
BL = BL - 1;
if (BL>=0)
{
    goto lbl_@@1;
}
```

and `@@` is used for local labels.  For further reading take a look at [this answer to the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43823619/11988587).